# Date getting compared as string in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to compare dates in the below collection

> $db.notifications.find() { "_id" :
>   ObjectId("51a4467be4b0142fc8b80eda"), "time" : "Tue May 28 11:24:03
>   IST 2013", "KEY" : "VALUE1" } { "_id" :
>   ObjectId("51a4467be4b0142fc8b80edb"), "time" : "Tue May 28 11:24:03
>   IST 2013", "KEY" : "VALUE2" }

using

> $db.notifications.find({ "time" : { "$gt" : "Fri May 31 00:00:00 IST
>   2013"}})

but what I am observing is that it is comparing treating "time" as
String an not as Date and thus the second command is returning me both
the entries.

> $ db.notifications.find({ "time" : { "$gt" : "Fri May 31 00:00:00 IST
>   2013"}}) { "_id" : ObjectId("51a4467be4b0142fc8b80eda"), "time" : "Tue
>   May 28 11:24:03 IST 2013", "KEY" : "VALUE1" } { "_id" :
>   ObjectId("51a4467be4b0142fc8b80edb"), "time" : "Tue May 28 11:24:03
>   IST 2013", "KEY" : "VALUE2" }

Can you please help me with the correct query and also let me know how
that correct version can be written in JAVA.

Thanks much !!

EDIT1 :

I am saving date using the below code

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
dateFormat.setLenient(false);
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); 
String nowString = dateFormat.format(new Date()); 
Date nowDate = dateFormat.parse(nowString); 
input.put("formattedDate", nowDate);
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection(<collection name>);
DBObject dbObject = (DBObject) JSON.parse(input.toString());
collection.insert(dbObject);"
```

and querying using

```
DBObject query = QueryBuilder.start().put("formattedDate")
                                     .greaterThan(prevDate).get();
DBCursor cursorDocJSON = collection.find(query);
```

I see that I am saving "time" as Date only. Why is still there an issue?

Comment: it's doing that because you are storing it as a string!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your date was stored as a String and not as an ISODate.  If it were stored as a real date and not a string, you'd see something like:

```
> db.MyCollection.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a4e4aa3004bc68e4f499e5"), "date" : ISODate("2000-09-29T23:00:00Z") }
```

Make sure when you're saving the "time" field that you're inserting it as a Date.  If you're using the Java driver to insert the values, you need to make sure that time field is a java.util.Date when you add it to DBObject (assuming you're using the Java driver directly and not some third party library).

When you've inserted it as a date then you should be able to perform the types of queries you want, using ISODate values from the shell or Date via the Java driver.

Comment: I am saving date using the below code 

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS").;
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    String nowString = dateFormat.format(new Date());
    Date nowDate = dateFormat.parse(nowString);
    input.put("time", nowDate);
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection(<collection name>);
    DBObject dbObject = (DBObject) JSON.parse(input.toString());
    collection.insert(dbObject);


Can you please help me understand my mistake here.

Comment: The code in your comment is creating a new Date object (new Date()), using SimpleDateFormatter to turn it into a String (dateFormat.format(new Date()), turning it *back* into a Date object (dateFormat.parse(nowString)).  You'll get the same result in a lot less lines of code by doing input.put("time", new Date());
But that will still be wrong.  What type is input and what else is in it?

Answer (score 0):

I think your date should be an ISODate object. currently its a string in your query. try something like below.

```
db.coll.find({"time" : { $gte : new ISODate("2013-05-28T20:18:00Z") }});
```

Also, [**related link**](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/)

Comment: this is the query that is getting executed.

>>> db.notifications.find({ "time" : { "$gt" : { "$date" : "2013-05-24T18:30:00.000Z"}}})